# LinkedList in C error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am attempting to write a LinkedList in C. Here are my two structs

```
struct node{
  int key;
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};

struct LinkedList {
  struct node *head;
};
```

And here is how I create a new node.

```
void createNode(int key, int value) {
  struct node *new_node;
  new_node->key = key;
  new_node->value = value;
  new_node->next = lList->head;
  lList->head = new_node;
}
```

I am trying to traverse through the LinkedList using the function below.

```
void traverseNode(struct LinkedList *lList) {
  struct node current = *lList->head;
  while(current != NULL) {
    printf("%i", current->key);
    current = current->next;
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting an error saying

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('struct node'
      and 'void *')
```

in relation to my `while` expression.

Also, I get an error for the

```
printf("%i", current->key);
current = current->next
```

with the error being

> member reference type 'struct node' is not a pointer;
>         maybe you meant to use '.'

I am confused because I thought in my node struct, the `*next` was defined as a pointer and could therefore be accessed only using the indirection(->) syntax.

I am a beginner to pointers, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant compare `NULL` with non-pointer type.

Declare variable `current` as pointer + remove dereference of `head` and it will compile

```
struct node * current = lList->head;
            ^          ^
while(current != NULL)  // Now you can compare them
```

---

You are getting SEGFAULT because you are dereferencing uninitialized pointer. Allocate enough memory on heap (dynamic storage duration).

```
struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

---

Since `current` is pointer

```
printf("%i", current->key);
current = current->next;
```

should be OK now.

Comment: When I do that, I get the following error,
initializing 'struct node *' with an expression of
      incompatible type 'struct node'; remove *

Comment: So, it compiles but when I run it I get a `segmentation fault: 11`. Is this because I am not assigning memory using `malloc` when I create a new node in my `void createNode` method?

Comment: Yes it is the problem.

Comment: Even after including the `malloc` line, I still get the Seg Fault error. Any idea why?

Comment: [Here(click)](https://ideone.com/f626RH) is a working code, you may inspire there :-)

Answer (score 2):

As the error states current is a structure, not the pointer

change it to `struct node *current = lList -> head;`

remember that pointer itself does not have the storage for the referenced object

Answer (score 1):

```
do{
printf("%i", current->key);
current = current->next;
} while(current != NULL)
```

doing this instead will check if your on the last node by seeing if the next node is null rather than the whole structure

Answer (score 0):

```
void createNode(int key, int value) {
  struct node *new_node; // you need to malloc here
  new_node->key = key;
  new_node->value = value;
  new_node->next = lList->head;
  lList->head = new_node;
}
```

You must malloc before access a pointer.

```
struct node *new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Also change like,

```
struct node current = *lList->head;
```

into,

```
struct node *current = *lList->head;
```

Comment: It wont work... :-) look at bottom lines, assigning `struct node` to `struct node*`.

Comment: which line u meant?